# Issue with sending Base64 encoded query string in aASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a web site in .Net 3.5 , I am converting the string into Base64String to send it through querystring. The Response.Redirect works fine for smaller string. But if the original string size is 1670, the response.redirect results in error "Page can not be found".

item is the string in below code snippet.

byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(item);
return Convert.ToBase64String(data)

Can any one please help in resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query string shouldn't be used for long values - while it depends on the browser and web server exactly what the maximum safe length is, it's certainly not safe above about 2000 characters, and I'd be wary about relying on it above 255. The solution is to use a POST request instead, or possibly to save the data on the server and pass a key to it in the query string.

Comment: Let me ask you this, I'm using an .ashx file to pass a file to a client. Upon calling this handler I check to make sure the file is owned by this client via session and database values. The client insists that the query string(database item id) is encrypted, the issue is that the short encrypted value sometimes results in chars such as a plus sign that get converted to whitespace. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on characters sent as a query string - it varies from browser to browser:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/

I'd save it to a DB and retrieve it on the other end with a key.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. I also wanted to save the querystring data in session, since I am migrating the older site, thought of contnuing with the same approach. However samething is working correctly in the existing site.

Comment: It really depends on how sensitive the data in the query string is. If it's regular ViewState page data, you could just save it to Session and retrieve it in the init method of the destination page? Alternatively, you could look at Cross Page Posting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28VS.90%29.aspx